# Box Cloud Storage - Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, online-storage

Using [this resource](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-expandrive-for-linux-ubuntu-centos.html#) I have installed ExpanDrive 7 since earlier methods of connecting to Box appear to have been deprecated.

Problem is that ExpanDrive is not FOSS...

[image]

https://www.expandrive.com/desktop/buy/

Is there another method still existing of connecting to a Box account for online storage of backups? My Box account is 2TB of free storage and therefore an extremely useful resource to maintain.

Comment: [rclone](https://rclone.org/install/) would be one option. It’s not the simplest thing in the world to set up but, once running, you’ll be good 

Comment: @matigo Thank you but will rclone connect directly to Box in the same way such that box becomes, like Google-Drive another drive accessible directly from Nautilus?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the location and set up the sync in a manner similar to a mount. From there, you'll have access to the Box storage and anything you modify in that location will be properly synchronized. You can even set rclone to use hash checks rather than timestamp checks for files that sync on Box, which is nice.

Comment: Not so much bothered about the sync (that need is met by Dropbox) but just a resource for the ubuntu backup tool daily backups. I don't need to have copies of the backups locally.